# Why do I get the number 1 instead of the desired affiliation for the authors in elsarticle template?

Tags: templates, labels, elsarticle

I am using for the first time the Latex template of Elsiver journals but I get the number 1 for the later affiliations of all the authors. Here is a minimal working environment. Could anyone tell if there is something missing?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My title}
\author[affiliation1, affiliation2]{Author1}
\author[affiliation3, affiliation5]{Author2}
\author[affiliation2]{Author3}
\author[affiliation3, affiliation4, affiliation6]{Author4}

\address[affiliation1]
{
 Institute1
}
\address[affiliation3]
{
 Institute2
}
\address[affiliation5]
{
 Institute3
}
\address[affiliation2]
{
 Institute4
}
\address[affiliation4]
{
 Institute5
}
\address[affiliation6]
{
 Institute6
}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have no space in the comma separated list of values in the optional argument:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My title}
\author[affiliation1,affiliation2]{Author1}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation5]{Author2}
\author[affiliation2]{Author3}
\author[affiliation3,affiliation4,affiliation6]{Author4}

\address[affiliation1]
{%
 Institute1%
}
\address[affiliation3]
{%
 Institute2%
}
\address[affiliation5]
{%
 Institute3%
}
\address[affiliation2]
{%
 Institute4%
}
\address[affiliation4]
{%
 Institute5%
}
\address[affiliation6]
{%
 Institute6%
}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The class uses internally `\@for`, which doesn't prune off leading or trailing spaces around commas.

Watch out for spaces!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I get 1,1 for the first 2 authors and 1,1,1 for the last one! I cannot get your results! Is there any thing possibly wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik Did you compile twice?

Comment: Okay, no I get your results, thanks! Do you know how can I get numbers instead of letters? Thanks!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik That's the style Elsevier wants.

Comment: Okay, no problems then, thanks again for your quick / smart answer :)

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik `\renewcommand{\theaffn}{\arabic{affn}}`